# XPath Not Finding Match

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML document:

```
<report>
    <ProcessorInfo
        xmlns="http://SITE/monitor"
        xmlns:SOAP="http://SITE/envelope/">
        <count>8</count>
    </ProcessorInfo>
</report>
```

when I try to query the following XPath: `//ProcessorInfo`, it says No match was found (I . If i remove the `xmlns`'s, my issue is fixed. What is the proper XPath to use without having to remove `xmlns`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
//*[local-name()='ProcessorInfo']
```

That will remove the namespace from the search criteria.